VS_SSIS_Slowly Changing Dimension
I would like to ask. in VS, SSIS Project, I am trying to set up variable in Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard, but there is no dropdown list for vaiablo, also when I set it up manually, I am not able to do next step.
I tried to restart VS without help, was checking Developer Community but there is nothing.

Where are you trying to use a variable with the SCD?
